# Select records that do not have a product associated on a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table PL:

| plid | plname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Danielle |

And table PLproducts

| plid | productIdentifier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | membership |
| 1 | life |
| 1 | dental |
| 2 | membership |
| 3 | membership |
| 3 | life |
| 3 | auto |

I need to find those plid where productIdentifier does not contain "dental"

Expected results:

| plid | plname |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Danielle |

If I Outer Join for PLproducts <> 'dental', I get all the records that do not contain 'dental' but that is not what Im looking for.

I've never found this scenario before. I understand it may be a simple question.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for where something does *not exist*

```
select * 
from pl
where not exists (
  select * from plProducts p 
    where p.plid = pl.plid and p.productidentifier = 'dental'
);
```

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you so much Stu. I was stuck on this.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem. You might be interested in looking at `cross apply`. It could be a useful approach in more complicated scenarios.

```
select pl.*
from pl cross apply (
    select count(*) as hasdental from plproducts pp
    where pp.plid = pl.plid and p2.productidentifier = 'dental'
) as oa
where hasdental = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Shawnt00, I will try this solution too. Always happy to learn new stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods is using string_agg and then use having to remove the phrases that includes "dental".

```
select * from PL p1
where p1.plid in
(select p2.plid from PLproducts p2
group by p2.plid 
having STRING_AGG(productIdentifier,';') NOT LIKE N'%dental%')
```

Comment: Note that this only works when there is at least one other value in `PLproducts` for the same `plid`. If you are going to use aggregation like that, probably easier to use conditional aggregation `having count(case when productIdentifier = 'dental' then 1 end) = 0`